# ES Sort by existance of specific value in multivalue field

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I need to sort - 1st by existance of "shop_1" in "available", 2nd by "price" ascending.

```
{
   "pID": 1,
   "available": ["shop_1", "shop_3"],
   "price": 100
}
{
   "pID": 2
   "available": ["shop_2", "shop_4"],
   "price": 50
}
{
   "pID": 3,
   "available": ["shop_1"],
   "price": 200
}
{
   "pID": 4,
   "available": ["shop_4"],
   "price": 10
}

So the result would be pID: 1, 3, 4, 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe something like below should work

Here if shop_1 is available , then we are increasing the score by 10 , this would be way higher than any reciprocal of price field can give.
Sum of these two will ensure that we get what you are looking for.

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "boost_mode": "replace",
      "score_mode": "sum",
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "available": "shop_1"
            }
          },
          "weight": 10
        },
        {
          "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "price",
            "modifier": "reciprocal"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```